# cell type and if condition

Tags: matlab, if-statement, cell

I have a cell 1x200 `B` and I want to use it in an if condition. Here an exemple with an 1x4 cell

```
1x4 cell
8   []  []  []
```

that I search is to say :
if all cell exept the first are empty (other saying 1x0 double) so I return at the begin of the initial loop else I applied other things. I start with this but it doesn't work :

```
if B{1,2:end}==[]
           return
else
bla bla bla
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
if isempty([B{1,2:end}])
    disp('Cells are empty');
```